# Json api does not return all metadata

Tags: custom-field, plugin-json-api

I am using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/

to create a new entry is saved correctly in the database all the wp_postmeta customfield table, but when you run `api/get_post/?post_type=job_listing&post_id=542`
the result is not complete, only gives me some customfield.

exampler:

```
meta_key               meta_value
_company_phone          89998983               //not shown
_company_website        www.exampler.cl        //not shown
geolocation_LOG         -36.98898838          //if displayed
geolocation_lat         -76.98898838          //if displayed
```

Comment: You can see from your example that the API will exclude any meta with an underscore `_` prefix - in WordPress this implies the data is private.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic as an answer please :)

Comment: I then just remove the underscore before?

Comment: Were you able to ever get this to work? Maybe the api doesn't support metadata?

Answer (score 2):

As @TheDeadMedic mentioned the API will exclude any meta with underscore. It's not a good idea to remove the underscore as it might break something in your code or dependencies, however you can try adding a code like this in your functions.php to unprotect the desired meta

```
add_filter( 'is_protected_meta', 'wp692_meta_unprotect', 10, 2 );
function wp692_meta_unprotect( $protected, $meta_key ) {
    return $meta_key == '_company_phone' ? false : $protected;
}
```

Comment: thanks, this code is hit or should I edit something?

Comment: You can add this as it is but I wrote it for one meta key '_company_phone' .. You can follow the pattern for other meta keys.

Comment: Add this code to my theme functions.php son and me did not work, my father does not work issue.

Comment: I realized that now appear in the editor section of wordpress custom fields, but does not appear in the json

Comment: Also not able to get this to work.  My function is not being called when I hit the Json Api endpoint.